# How to implement simple list with spinner in every row?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working with openERP mobile app.

In openERP tree view like this,

[image]

If we press **Add an item** button,

It display the spinner & we select the item from spinner.

Then selected item added into list.

Can I implement in android list. I am a beginner.Any one help me?

Any suggestion or comments are welcome.

Comment: Can u post your code so i can help you?

Comment: I don`t know how to implement this design.I want suggestion only. not code.

Comment: How about filling your list with the value of the adapter and a boolean key to show or not to show in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Add a spinner on the adapter of your Product listview, this way we will know which location to add the new item. When your done adding that item to your array, call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` of your product listView.

ProductListViewAdapter(containing existing products)
 (a) Add A spinner inside and show the items for selection
 (b) After that, retrieve the item selected in the spinner and create a new array of existing items
 (c) call this.items = your new items array
 (d) then call this.notifyDataSetChanged()

it will update your listview to new items.